# how to control output format when chinese characters and ascii mixed?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I find that it is difficult to make the text aligned.

```
table='''乘客姓名,性别,出生日期
HuangTianhui,男,1948/05/28
姜翠云,女,1952/03/27
李红晶,女,1994/12/09
LuiChing,女,1969/08/02
宋飞飞,男,1982/03/01
唐旭东,男,1983/08/03
YangJiabao,女,1988/08/25
买买提江·阿布拉,男,1979/07/10
安文兰,女,1949/10/20
胡偲婠(婴儿),女,2011/02/25
(有待确定姓名),男,1985/07/20
'''
data=[ [cell  for cell in row.split(",") ] for row in table.split("\n")  if row]
len0=max([ len(x[0])   for x in data])
len1=max([ len(x[1])   for x in data])
len2=max([ len(x[2])   for x in data])

for cell in data:
    print("_"*((len0+len1+len2)*2+4) )
    print("|%24s|%4s|%20s|" % (cell[0],cell[1],cell[2]))
```

[image]

Not every line is (12+2+10)*2+4  character width,the same format control statement ,but different output ,how can i fix it to make every line the same output format,same width?

Comment: Practically speaking, you can't.

Comment: Do you know why Python 3's string formatting does not work as expected out of the box? I would expect it to do just this, but maybe this is naive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not beautiful, but here's one way. (encode/decode with `bytes.rjust`)

```
table='''乘客姓名,性别,出生日期
HuangTianhui,男,1948/05/28
姜翠云,女,1952/03/27
李红晶,女,1994/12/09
LuiChing,女,1969/08/02
宋飞飞,男,1982/03/01
唐旭东,男,1983/08/03
YangJiabao,女,1988/08/25
提江·阿布拉,男,1979/07/10
安文兰,女,1949/10/20
胡偲婠(婴儿),女,2011/02/25
(有待确定姓名),男,1985/07/20
'''
table = table.encode('gb18030')
data = [[cell  for cell in row.split(b",")]
        for row in table.split(b"\n")  if row]
len0 = max([len(x[0]) for x in data])
len1 = max([len(x[1]) for x in data])
len2 = max([len(x[2]) for x in data])

for cell in data:
    print("_" * (len0+len1+len2+4))
    line = (
        b"|" + cell[0].rjust(len0) +
        b"|" + cell[1].rjust(len1) +
        b"|" + cell[2].rjust(len2) + b"|"
    )
    print(line.decode('gb18030'))
```

output:

[image]

Comment: i have tried it,that method can treat greek characater correctly.

Comment: The line `提江·阿布拉,男,1979/07/10` in the source is missing the initial `买买`. @it_is_a_literature, you can see that the display of ambiguous characters depends on the font/terminal. Sometimes they're wide, but in the above the `'·'` character is printed narrow. Encoded in GB18030 it's 2 bytes, so the printout is missing a pad space to line up data[8][0] correctly in the table. This method is only reliable with ASCII mixed with Chinese characters, but that's what you asked for.

Comment: there are two methods :1.@falsetry method ,when i add 买买 in the 8th row ,and add greek character in other row,it can display it correctly .2. @Robᵩ ,to revise return sum(unicodedata.east_asian_width(x)=='W' for x in s) into return sum(unicodedata.east_asian_width(x)=='W' or unicodedata.east_asian_width(x)=='A' for x in s) ,otherwise it can not display ambiguous characters correctly.

Answer (score 7):

You could take into account the number of fullwidth vs halfwidth characters in the string:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# coding=utf8

import unicodedata

def wide_chars(s):
    return sum(unicodedata.east_asian_width(x)=='W' for x in s)
def width(s):
    return len(s) + wide_chars(s)

table='''乘客姓名,性别,出生日期
HuangTianhui,男,1948/05/28
姜翠云,女,1952/03/27
李红晶,女,1994/12/09
LuiChing,女,1969/08/02
宋飞飞,男,1982/03/01
唐旭东,男,1983/08/03
YangJiabao,女,1988/08/25
买买提江·阿布拉,男,1979/07/10
安文兰,女,1949/10/20
胡偲婠(婴儿),女,2011/02/25
(有待确定姓名),男,1985/07/20
'''
data=[ [cell  for cell in row.split(",") ] for row in table.split("\n")  if row]
len0=max([ width(x[0])   for x in data])
len1=max([ width(x[1])   for x in data])
len2=max([ width(x[2])   for x in data])

for cell in data:
    print("_"*((len0+len1+len2)*2+4) )
    print("|%*s|%*s|%*s|" % (24-wide_chars(cell[0]), cell[0],
                               4-wide_chars(cell[1]),cell[1],
                               20-wide_chars(cell[2]), cell[2]))
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: To revise `return sum(unicodedata.east_asian_width(x)=='W' for x in s)` into `return sum(unicodedata.east_asian_width(x)=='W' or unicodedata.east_asian_width(x)=='A'  for x in s)` can get more better display in console.